# How to fix: errorjava.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException for pig latin translator

Tags: java, regex

In my pig latin translator I am getting:

errorjava.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 10
[C@55f96302

Every time I compile it.

My code has two methods one to remove the special character at the end of the user input and split the words up, and another to actually translate the words.

Here is my code:

```
package midtermPigLatin;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import textio.TextIO;
public class midtermPigLatin {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String yourSentence="", line = "", single,line1 = "", pigLatin = "";
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        Scanner word = new Scanner(line);
        String[] words;
        char[] special = {'.', '?','!'};
        String specialChar = special.toString();
        boolean again = true;
        try {
             System.out.print("Enter your words here: ");

            label1: while(input.hasNextLine())
             {
                 line = input.nextLine();

                 line1 = line.replaceAll(specialChar, "");
                 word = new Scanner (line);

             while(word.hasNext())
             {
                single = word.next();
                pigLatin = pigLatin(single);

             if (word.hasNext())
             {
                 System.out.print(pigLatin + " " );
             }
             else if(!word.hasNext())
             {
                 System.out.print( pigLatin);
            break label1;
             }
             }
             }
            }catch(Exception errMsg)
             {
                System.out.print(" error" + errMsg);
             }

    }
public static String pigLatin(String single)
{

    String newWord = "";
    try 
    {

                if (single.startsWith("a") || single.startsWith("e") || single.startsWith("i") || single.startsWith("o") || single.startsWith("u"))
                    newWord = (single + "way ");
                else if (single.startsWith("sh") || single.startsWith("ch") || single.startsWith("th"))
                    newWord =(single.substring(2)+single.substring(0,2)+"ay ");
                else
                    newWord = (single.substring(1)+single.substring(0,1)+"ay ");

       }

    catch (Exception errMsg)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in special" + errMsg);
    }
return newWord;
}
}
```

Per my professors rules I need to have at least two methods and try-catches so
I can't take those out.

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new but I don't know how to find the exception stack trace.

Comment: Sorry compile error not runtime error I got it.

Answer (score 0):

In the String class [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) uses a regex not a single character. `.` and `?` are special characters in regex they mean any character or optional respectively.

There is two ways you could solve this.

1 Use [`String.replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) it takes a single character and replaces every occurrence of that character. You should also make it a `String[]` and then loop through each string and replace it.

```
String[] special = {".", "?", "!"};
for(String specialChar : special) {
    line = line.replace(specialChar, "");
}
```

2 You could change your char[] to a String and use real regex

```
String[] specialChar = "[\\.\\?!]"
```

Either will take care of your compile error.

Update:

I forgot Java makes you escape `\`

Comment: I tried both but for the 2nd one, I get an invalid escape error and for the 1st one it says I can't convert, unless I am doing it wrong/